# How to reload the remote file list in Coda?

Tags: mac, text-editors, coda

Anyone know how to convince Panic's Coda to reload a directory and file list for a remote server?

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> with focus in the file list looks like it's doing something, but it doesn't actually do anything.

Eject and reconnect is a poor answer, so please don't suggest that.

Comment: or just a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Coda support team answered on twitter instead of here:

> Right-click in the sidebar; or, use
>   the Actions button at the bottom of
>   the sidebar.

The right click option didn't seem to work at first, but it turns out it's just not recursive.  You have to do it in the directories you care about, not just their parent.